# How conditional argument used in `db.Exec` command using golang

Tags: go

I have a query string with optional fields inside a function like :

```
func (s *RepairClosesStore) UpdateByCondition(rc RepairClose, userID string, remoteUser string) (err error) {

    log.Println("repairclosesStore.go : UpdateByCondition method started")
    strQry := `
                UPDATE 
                    repaircloses 
                SET 
                    dispatchNumber = ?,
                    runDate = ?,
                    servicePerformed = ?,
                    notes = ? ,
                    repairCode = ?,
                    serialNumber = ? ,
                    repairSuccessful =?,
                    statusCode = ? ,
                    repairCloseFinished = ?,
                    billingFinished = ? ,
                    updateUserID = ? ,
                    updateRemoteUser = ?,
                    updateTimestamp = NOW()`

        //Checks repairCloseFinished
        if rc.RepairCloseFinished {

            //Append strQry query
            strQry += ` ,closeUserID = ?,
                        closeRemoteUser = ?,
                        closeTimeStamp = NOW()`
        }

        //Checks billingFinished
        if rc.BillingFinished {

            //Append strQry query
            strQry += ` ,billingFinishUserID = ?,
                        billingFinishRemoteUser = ?,
                        billingFinishTimeStamp = NOW()`

        }

        //Append strQry query
        strQry += ` WHERE RepairCloseID = ? `



 query, err := s.DB.Prepare(strQry)

queryArgs := []interface{
        rc.DispatchNumber,
        rc.RunDate,
        rc.ServicePerformed,
        rc.Notes,
        rc.RepairCode,
        rc.SerialNumber,
        rc.RepairSuccessful,

    }

    resp, err := query.Exec(queryArgs)
}
```

This is the entire function i used but the problem is there that i don't know how to append optional parameter inside Exec command to execute with conditional parameters.

please help me.

Comment: Make a `[]interface{}` out of the non-conditional fields, and then, if the condition is met, append those that are conditional. After that do `query.Exex(a...)`.

Comment: I used this one but it showing an error "rc is not a package" here rc is the struct from which i get the values.

Comment: Please update your code example, also show where the code in question gets access to `rc`.

Comment: yes please see the modification.

Comment: Something like this: https://play.golang.org/p/zvSyxiHPjR

Comment: Also the type of the slice elements is the empty interface so when you construct it you need to include the curly braces; `[]interface{}{elem1, elem2, ...}`.

Comment: And you need to "unpack" the args at the end, `query.Exec(queryArgs)` is not gonna match the columns, you need to do `query.Exec(queryArgs...)`.

Comment: yes Thanks @mkopriva its working